# Where are the descriptions of the Trove classifiers for setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, pypi

I started packaging some python code more seriously, with setuptools. However, there is a metadata argument to `setup()` which is called `classifiers`.

Is there anywhere a description/definition of each item listed [here](https://pypi.org/classifiers/)?

It seems nice to provide standardized metadata, but what's the point if they don't have any well-defined meaning? I'm sorry but it might not be obvious to everyone, especially beginners like me, whether they should use for instance:

```
Operating System :: POSIX
Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux
Operating System :: Unix
```

or whether "Unix" means the unix family of OS's including Mac OS X, or just the original Unix, etc.

Comment: There are no such strict definitions. They aren't standardized metadata in a strict sense. An author of a package is free to choose classifiers and users of the package are free to interpret them.